# DELETE FROM multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I have two conditions in a DELETE MySQL statement. But it does not delete the record.

```
$sql="DELETE * FROM sportevent.event_registrations WHERE event_registrations.id = '$id' AND event_registration.eventname = $event";
```

Is there something wrong with my query? It works if I use only one WHERE condition, but I need to use two.

Comment: how exactly it does NOT work? error happens, does not delete what you expect?

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html there should not be a * in 'DELETE * FROM', but rather just 'DELETE FROM'.

Comment: Retrieve any errors from MySQL if the query returns `false`. This way you don't have to take stabs into the dark!

Comment: Hi yes, the query is submitted through when a user clicks on Cancel button. But currently it does nothing

Comment: This is incorrect. The `*` doesn't belong in DELETE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this:

```
event_registration.eventname = $event
```

should be

```
event_registrations.eventname = $event
```

After all, you've used the plural form in both the "from" clause and the other part of the "where".

Also note that only one of your parameters is quoted - it's not clear to me how you're providing the parameters, but surely you should be consistent.

Comment: Hi, thanks, didn't see the spelling.It still ignores the query. Am i using the right condition operators?

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes, using 'and' should be fine, assuming that's what you actually mean. Did you fix the quoting issue I mentioned? What happens if you do a normal select query with the same parameters - does that return you the rows you want to delete?

Comment: Hi, it seems the $event which is posted is empty thus nothing changed. Thanks for the great answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$sql="DELETE FROM sportevent event_registrations WHERE event_registrations.id = '$id' AND event_registrations.eventname = $event";
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The `*` doesn't belong in DELETE